# Escape characters being printed to yorick shell

Tags: yorick

I’m working with the [Yorick language](http://yorick.sourceforge.net) on Yosemite. I’ve been able to successfully install the source code and start up the Yorick shell. However, using keyboard input at the shell (e.g. delete, up arrow, etc …) prints out the escape sequence ( `^H` and `^[[A`, respectively) to the command line.

```
$ yorick
 Copyright (c) 2005.  The Regents of the University of California.
 All rights reserved.  Yorick 2.1.06 ready.  For help type 'help'
> ^H      # delete 
> ^[[A    # up arrow
```

Is this type of response specific to the language's interpreter? Or is there some bash configuration I can implement to get the desired response of ‘erase' and 'recall command history' for these inputs?

Comment: It seems that your interpreter is not built with [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) support.  What you see is normal for processes that don't interpret those control inputs. What are you expecting from hitting those buttons?  The shell cannot do anything about this because as soon as a foreground process is started, it no longer controls the terminal.

Comment: Ah, 'readline' was the term I was looking for. You seem to be correct: http://yorick.sourceforge.net/environ.php. It looks like there might be a solution using `rlwrap` (https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple fix.

> The readline package is incompatible with Yorick (your graphics window
>   goes dead when readline blocks waiting for keyboard input)

However, I was able to install [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) via

```
$ brew install rlwrap
```

Which acts as a GNU readline wrapper to run the shell in.

```
$ rlwrap yorick
# Now delete and up arrow work
```